# Disappears tab on statistics page

Tags: bug, site-analytics

If you have 25k+ reputation, you have access to the site statistic. On this page history tab has two tabs. But if you open sources tab, there is no sources tab. Looks inconsistent.

> [image: gif'ка]

Could you add sources tab button?